# Invalid Username When Developing a QGIS Plugin on Mac

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

On a fresh Mac OSX 10.8 install, I've installed Quantum GIS from Kingchaos binaries and it's running fine. I'm trying to develop a plugin for QGIS using Plugin Builder. The skel that Plugin Builder produces should work off-the-shelf, but it does not compile using the makefile. Somewhere python can't find (`pyuic.py`), and it searches for the `/Users/kyngchaos/...` path. This user does not exist on my system:(

Here are my ENVS on .profile:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib:/Applications/Qgis.app/Contents/Frameworks"
export PATH="/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

Here is the ouptput of make:

```
Arthur@teste:make
pyuic4 -o ui_teste.py ui_teste.ui
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/kyngchaos/Applications/qgis-python27/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
make: *** [ui_teste.py] Error 2
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

A hackish workaround would be to create a symlink with that username to your own home dir. But it seems either `ui_teste.py` or `ui_teste.ui` has that path hardcoded, so check them out (or search the whole hierarchy where they are for "kyngchaos"). There's also a chance the pyqt4 package you installed is buggy, but first try the previous suggestion.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping!
The fix was, edit /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pyuic4
and correct the path, like this:
#!/bin/sh
exec pythonw2.7 /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py ${1+"$@"}

Answer (score 0):

I have recently committed a fix for this in the [CMake build commands](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/mac/cmake/1qt.cmake.in#L123). I would appreciate if you can test the resultant file under Mt. Lion, which would have the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec pythonw2.7 "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$0")/../../Resources/python/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py" ${1+"$@"}
```

This fix is in the [nightly Mac builds available here](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/). The fix should allow you to move the app wherever you like in the file system (no hard-coded path). If you do move the app from /Applications remember to update your PYTHONPATH accordingly for plugin development.